# Get Hive partition's values using Map Reduce (HCatalog)

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

Given a Hive table as shown below which is partitioned on gender, I would like to know the partition column's values. So, for this table the values for gender are (male, female). :

```
── table
    ├── gender=male
    └── gender=female
```

Can we achieve this using Map Reduce program using HCatalog related libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in Hive by running a show partitions statement.

```
show partitions yourDatabaseName.yourTableName;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I m looking to accomplish this using MapReduce.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT gender FROM table;`